# How to merge a serialize date with an array for ajax post?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

How can I merge a serialize date with an array with jquery for ajax post?

For instance,

```
var array = { name: "John", time: "2pm" };

$.post( "page.php", $("form").serialize() + array);
```

I get this,

```
Array
(
    [url] => another test
    [page_id] => 140
    [method] => update[object Object]
)
```

What can I do so I can merge them and get this as my result below?

```
Array
(
    [url] => another test
    [page_id] => 140
    [method] => update
    [name] => John
    [time] => 2pm
)
```

Comment: use hidden fields in your form `name` and `time` and initialize them with values you want

Comment: See also Underscore.js's extend function: http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#extend

Comment: Keep in mind that on the client side, your var `array` isn't an `array`, it's an `object`. You can simply loop through the properties of one object and add them to the second, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to serialize an array/object

```
var array = { name: "John", time: "2pm" };

$.post( "page.php", $("form").serialize() + '&' + $.param(array));
```

Comment: thanks but I get this only Array
`(
    [name] => John
    [time] => 2pm
)`

Comment: Happy to hear this :)